# How to set a variable the same as another without first word?

Tags: variables, batch-file, cpu-word, words

I need to pull all words from a variable in my batch script without the first word to another variable.

ex

if %hello% had "apples are awesome" (without quotes) in it and was pulled and put into %hi%

%hi% would say "are awesome" (without quotes)

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ("%hello%") do set "hi=%%b"
echo %hi%
```

should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a string by any of " ", ",", and ";":

```
set myvar=a b,c;d
for %%a in (%myvar%) do echo %%a
```

Splitting a string by semicolon, assuming the string contains no quotation marks:

```
@echo off
set myvar=a b;c;d
set strippedvar=%myvar%
:repeat
for /f "delims=;" %%a in ("%strippedvar%") do echo %%a
set prestrippedvar=%strippedvar%
set strippedvar=%strippedvar:*;=%
if not "%prestrippedvar:;=%"=="%prestrippedvar%" goto :repeat
```

see if this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
set "hello=apples are awesome"
set "hi=%hello:* =%"
echo %hi%
```

The second line eliminate characters in `hello` variable from beginning up to the first space, including it.